# System.accessviolationexception in nunit test

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nunit

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 / C# with nUnit test, and get System.AccessViolationException on simple test...

When I launch the "Execute Test" option, the test returns OK.
When I launch the "Debug Test" option, I get System.AccessViolationException.

Screen Capture of the Exception - Sorry french one !

[image]

Adding "break on all exceptions" option, I get this (again, sorry, french) :

```
L'assembly nommé 'nunit.engine.api' a été chargé à partir de
'file:///C:/USERS/ALAIN/APPDATA/LOCAL/MICROSOFT/VISUALSTUDIO/11.0/EXTENSIONS/CZBUZRPC.SXP/nunit.engine.api.DLL'
à l'aide du contexte LoadFrom. L'utilisation de ce contexte peut provoquer un
comportement inattendu lors des opérations de sérialisation, de conversion et de
résolution de dépendance. Dans la grande majorité des cas, il est recommandé
d'éviter le contexte LoadFrom. Pour ce faire, il suffit d'installer les assemblys
dans le Global Assembly Cache ou dans le répertoire ApplicationBase et d'utiliser
Assembly.Load lors du chargement explicite des assemblys.
```

I think something in my config is not good. I'm pretty sure the source is good and has no hidden bug.

Any help will help.

Here is the code :

Class1.cs

```
using System;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public String test = "1";
        public Class1()
        {
        }

        public void Test()
        {
            test = "2";
        }
    }
}
```

UnitTest1.cs

```
using ClassLibrary1;
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Class1 classe = new Class1();
            Assert.AreEqual(classe.test, "1");
            classe.Test();
            Assert.AreEqual(classe.test, "2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack trace or....

Comment: @hoodaticus : What do you mean ?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that reveals the problem, so having the stack trace that we know you have from the exception you told us was thrown will help determine the problem.

Comment: OK. I get a modal window with the error. I'll try to had exception catch.

Comment: If you can see the exception in Visual Studio, you should be able to click on it and see the Call Stack or Stack Trace of the exception.  If you can copy that to us or even take a screenshot it will help.

Comment: @hoodaticus : As I explained into the primary message, I get error on debug mode, not in execution mode. When I try to had exception catch, no exception is catched.

Comment: I can put the screen capture of the modal exception thrown by the interface. But do not know how to do...

Comment: Have you tried using the Debug > .... Exceptions option to turn on the setting that causes Visual Studio to break on all exceptions?  Because if you can get the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown, then you can go the bottom of the screen and click on the Call Stack window and just copy and paste that here.

Comment: Adding "break on all exceptions" option on principal purpose